# How LOCK works for writing logs into flat file?

Tags: php, concurrency, fopen, fwrite, flat-file

Read concurrency of flat files is almost unlimited (correct me if I'm wrong); but how is the concurrency for write? Consider a simple access log writing (for visits) in PHP as to append a line of access detail ended with `\n`

```
fopen(); // in append mode
fwrite();
fclose();
```

Since we have concurrent visitors, how the system (one user which is the wbserver/php user) write the view logs concurrently?

My confusion is: the function `file_put_contents()` (which is a wrapper of the above three functions) has an option for locking (`LOCK_EX`)? Is it beneficial to use this locking option? How this will affect the log writing?

**UPDATE:** My question is about how `LOCK`ing originally works/affects writing log to file. I do not compare `file_put_contents` and `fwrite`; even my question is not limited to `PHP`. The question is about locking a file during write process.

Comment: `file_put_contents()` does have an option for locking, check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: @YannisRizos As I quoted in the original question, I know that `file_put_contents` has `LOCK_EX`. My question is how it affects writing an access log.

Comment: Yes, you're right, obviously my comment was for the second revision of the question. Bad edit, that one.

Answer (score 3):

`file_put_contents()` does have an option for locking, but in my opinion, you should use `flock()` instead.

From manual:

> Available flags
>
> **FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH**
>   Search for filename in the include directory. See include_path for more
>   information.
>
> **FILE_APPEND**
>   If file filename already exists, append the data to the file instead of overwriting it.
>
> **LOCK_EX**
>   Acquire an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the writing.

`flock()` allows you to use other methods:

> **LOCK_SH** to acquire a shared lock (reader).
>   **LOCK_EX** to acquire an
>   exclusive lock (writer).
>   **LOCK_UN** to release a lock (shared or
>   exclusive).

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php and here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Be warned, file locking for access logs is an environment that can easily introduce a race condition. perhaps look into another method? logging to a database, maybe?  It's far too easy for a well-designed system to try to open and write to the log at the same time with parallel processes.

Maybe take a look at monolog? there's some logging handlers in there for async logging, which would be ideal for anything to do with access logging.

https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog

Comment: Nice to know about `monolog`; but this is a custom access log, not that of system. It can contain info from sessions, cookies, member login, etc. In addition, my question is in general for writing to disk.

Comment: @Ali You need to be very careful then if it's going to be hooked up to anything chatty; the more often you'll be logging data, the higher the chance of having your code go to append to the log only to have it hit the file lock and be unable to log.  In this circumstance you need to either be logging to something on an SSD (fast write speed, but unlikely to have as server hardware), a ramdisk (fast write but unstable; lose power and the data is gone), or you can log to a spinny disk and cross your fingers and hope that nothing gets file-locked from writing to the log.